# WPF Image Viewer sample applications

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and just started learning WPF. I am looking for WPF Image viewer sample applications with brightness/Contrast, Zoom, Rotate, etc.. If you come accross such application please post the link. Thank you,
Harsha T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zoom, Pan example that worked for me:
http://blogs.windowsclient.net/joeyw/archive/2009/06/02/pan-and-zoom-updated.aspx

Answer (score 1):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#images would be a starting point and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873(VS.100).aspx has sample code for rotation etc.

Answer (score 1):

see [windowsclient.net WPF samples](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/default.aspx) and video tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for posting the link.